# Matlab skip overheader importing textfile (follow up)

Tags: matlab

I want to be able to import a file with 46 lines of headers and then 4 x6 columns of data. I tried using this example from a previous answer, but the textscan won't work.

here is my test file: ImportTest.txt

1.0 2.0 3.0
1.1 2.1 3.1
1.2 2.2 3.3

Here is the code. The strData is different sizes. Why?

```
%open file
fid = fopen('ImportTest.txt');
strData = textscan(fid,'%s%s%s%s', 'Delimiter',',')
fclose(fid);

%# catenate, b/c textscan returns a column of cells for each column in the data
strData = cat(2,strData{:}) ;

%# convert cols 3:6 to double
doubleData = str2double(strData(:,3:end));

%# find header rows. headerRows is a logical array
headerRowsL = all(isnan(doubleData),2);

%# since I guess you know what the headers are, you can just remove the header rows
dateAndTimeCell = strData(~headerRowsL,1:2);
dataArray = doubleData(~headerRowsL,:);

%# and you're ready to start working with your data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dlmread` function to read your input file:

```
header_rows=5;
delim_char=' ';
C=dlmread('ImportTest.txt',delim_char,header_rows,0)
```

In the call you can specify the numember of header rows to skip (header_rows, in the example) and the delimiter character (delim_char in the example).

The last parameter in the call (0) defines the colums where the data starts.

The data read fromt the text file are stored directly in an array (C in the example).

Given this imput file (with 5 header rows):

```
header line 1
header line 2 
header line 3 
header line 4 
header line 5 
1.0 2.0 3.0
1.1 2.1 3.1
1.2 2.2 3.3
```

the output will be:

```
C =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
    1.1000    2.1000    3.1000
    1.2000    2.2000    3.3000
```

As an alternative, you can use `importdata`

```
header_rows=5;
delim_char=' ';
c=importdata('ImportTest.txt',delim_char,header_rows)
```

In this case, the output will be a structure:

```
c = 

          data: [3x3 double]
      textdata: {5x3 cell}
    colheaders: {'header'  'line'  '5'}
```

The data are stored in the "data" field", the 5 header rows in the "textdata" field.

The last header row is also interpreted as the actual header of the data.

Hope this helps.

Qapla'